# How does one create a List<Guid> from components of a List<struct> item?

Tags: c#, struct

I have created a struct:

```
 public struct ProductShortInfo
            {
                public Guid Id { get; set; }

                public string Code { get; set; }

                public string Name { get; set; }

                public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }

                public string DownloadUrl { get; set; }
            }

public string PopulateStruct()
{
    List<ProductShortInfo> productShortData;

    using (SomeService service = new SomeService())
    {
         productShortData = service.populateShortData();
    }

    List<Guid> guidsFromProductShortData = //NEED SOLUTION
}
```

I want to isolate the Id's returned for use later in a List, but I cannot figure out the proper method. I really don't think a foreach loop is a very elegant way.  Theres probably a built in method for doing it.

EDIT: Found a solution less than 5 minutes later.  Linq.

List productShortDataIds = (from datas in productShortData select datas.Id).ToList();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) list of structs with LINQ:

```
List<Guid> guids = productShortData.Select(p => p.Id).ToList();
```